# How to create grand total from the sum of sub-totals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to sum all the subtotals I got into a grand total. This is for an assignment that I need to submit in about 2 weeks. Here's my JS file:

```
function calculate_Total() {
  for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    const idName = "price_" + i;
    const price = parseFloat(document.getElementById(idName).value);
    const idQty= "qty_" + i;
    const qty = parseFloat(document.getElementById(idQty).value);
    const total = price*qty;
    const idTotal = "total_" + i;
    document.getElementById(idTotal).value = total.toFixed(2);
  }

  for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    document.getElementById("grand_total").value = 0;
  }
}
```

I want to do that when I click a button to calculate the grand total price. Here's the HTML file that shows the button just near the end of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order a book!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/book-order.css">
    <script src="JS/book-order.js"></script>
    <script></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Book Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Category</label></th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onkeyup="calculate_Total()"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_1" min="0" value="0" onkeyup="calculate_Total()"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" onchange="calculate_Total()" readonly /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_2" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onkeyup="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_2" min="0" value="0" onkeyup="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_2" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly onchange="calculate_Total()"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_3" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onkeyup="calculate_Total()"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_3" min="0" value="0" onkeyup="calculate_Total()"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_3" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly onchange="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_4" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onkeyup="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_4" min="0" value="0" onkeyup="calculate_Total()"  /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_4" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly onchange="calculate_Total()"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_5" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onkeyup="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_5" min="0" value="0" onkeyup="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_5" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly onchange="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <div style="text-align: right">
                        <button onclick="discount()">View Price After 10% discount</button>
                        <button onclick="calculate_Total();">Calculate Grand Total Price</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <input type="number" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" value="0.00" readonly>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
<script src="js/book-order.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I sum the sub-totals into a grand total? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Initialize a variable with `0` before the loop, and then simply add your `total` to it ...?

Comment: That second for loop makes no sense of course, all that does is the exact same thing five times in a row.

Comment: You should add your HTML to the question too as there maybe a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

After you correctly calculated all subtotals (first `for` loop) you assigned the values to a series of html elements (the ones with ID `total_1`, `total_2`, `total_3`, `total_4`, `total_5`).

That allows you to iterete them in your second `for` loop, accumulating the value of each subtotal to a `grandTotal` variable.

After the loop is over, you can assign the result to the html element with ID `grand_total`.

```
function calculate_Total() {
  for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    const idName = "price_" + i;
    const price = parseFloat(document.getElementById(idName).value);
    const idQty= "qty_" + i;
    const qty = parseFloat(document.getElementById(idQty).value);
    const total = price*qty;
    const idTotal = "total_" + i;
    document.getElementById(idTotal).value = total.toFixed(2);
  }

  let grandTotal = 0
  for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    grandTotal += parseFloat(document.getElementById("total_" + i).value)
  }
  document.getElementById("grand_total").value = grandTotal;
}
```

Comment: Could you describe the solution?

Comment: But the button is not clicked when I executed the function. It just does it automatically.